# SPARQL query doesn't deliver desired results

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I've used the following code to list the band members of Punk Rock bands:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema>

SELECT distinct ?bandname ?bandmembername where {
?band
   foaf:name ?bandname;
   dbo:genre dbr:Punk_Rock.
?bandmember
   dbo:bandMember ?bandmember;
   rdfs:label ?bandmembername.
}
```

I would need the band members of any `Punk_Rock` band.

Comment: aha, cool. And where is the syntax error?! The only issue in your query is the wrong namespace declaration for `rdfs` missing the trailing `#`: `http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#`

Comment: The first part (?band...) does not have any variable in common with the second part (?bandmember ...)  Did you mean to use `?band dbo:bandMember ?bandmember;`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax error.

There are 2 errors in your query.

1. `PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema>` should be `PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>`
2. The `dbo:bandMember ?bandmember` predicate and object should be describing the `?band` (which has members), not describing `?bandmember` (which *is* the member)

With those fixes [in the query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20distinct%20%3Fbandname%20%20%3Fbandmembername%20%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fband%0D%0A%20%20%20foaf%3Aname%20%3Fbandname%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20dbo%3AbandMember%20%3Fbandmember%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20dbo%3Agenre%20dbr%3APunk_Rock%20.%0D%0A%3Fbandmember%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fbandmembername%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20), you should see [the results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20distinct%20%3Fbandname%20%20%3Fbandmembername%20%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fband%0D%0A%20%20%20foaf%3Aname%20%3Fbandname%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20dbo%3AbandMember%20%3Fbandmember%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20dbo%3Agenre%20dbr%3APunk_Rock%20.%0D%0A%3Fbandmember%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fbandmembername%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) you're hoping for --

```
PREFIX  dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?bandname ?bandmembername 
WHERE
{
  ?band
      foaf:name      ?bandname ;
      dbo:bandMember ?bandmember ;
      dbo:genre      dbr:Punk_Rock .
  ?bandmember 
      rdfs:label     ?bandmembername .
}
```